# Azure Function not closing connection, it is sleeping not finalizing

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-functions

I'm working with a Python V1 Azure Function App that receives an HTTP request and processes it. However, I'm facing an issue where the function doesn't seem to be closing its connection properly. Instead, it appears to be sleeping and not finalizing as expected.

Here's an example of the type of request it receives:

And here's the main function in my **init**.py file:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import azure.functions as func

def main(
    req: func.HttpRequest,
    tabproductsOldCategory: func.Out[func.SqlRow],
    tabproducts: func.Out[func.SqlRow],
) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(
        "Python HTTP trigger and SQL output binding function processed a request."
    )

    try:
        products = []
        OldCategory = []
        req_body = req.get_json()
        for item in req_body:
            if "num_pd" in item.keys():
                products.append(item)

            elif "num_sq" in item.keys():

                OldCategory.append(item)

            else:
                logging.error("Missing necessary fields: num_pd or num_sq")
                return func.HttpResponse(
                    "Missing necessary fields: num_pd or num_sq", status_code=400
                )

        logging.info(f"Processed request body. Found {len(products)} products and {len(OldCategory)} OldCategory.")
        rows_products = None
        rows_OldCategory = None

        if len(products) > 0:
            rows_products = func.SqlRowList(
                map(lambda r: func.SqlRow.from_dict(r), products)
            )
            logging.info(rows_products)
        if len(OldCategory) > 0:
            rows_OldCategory = func.SqlRowList(
                map(lambda r: func.SqlRow.from_dict(r), OldCategory)
            )
            logging.info(rows_OldCategory)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "An error occurred while processing your request.", status_code=500
        )

    try:

        if isinstance(rows_products, func.SqlRowList):
            logging.info("UPSERTING products")
            tabproducts.set(rows_products)
            logging.info("products UPSERTED")
        if isinstance(rows_OldCategory, func.SqlRowList):
            logging.info("UPSERTING OldCategory")
            tabproductsOldCategory.set(rows_OldCategory)
            logging.info("OldCategory UPSERTED")

        return func.HttpResponse(
            body=req.get_body(),
            status_code=201,
            mimetype="application/json",
        )
        
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info("An error occurred while upserting the rows into the SQL tables.")
        logging.error(f"Exception: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error processing request: {e}", status_code=400)
```

The issue I'm facing is that the function doesn't seem to be closing its connection properly. Instead, it appears to be sleeping and not finalizing as expected. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to process the HTTP request in my Azure Function App. I was expecting the function to process the request, handle the num_sq or num_pd field in the request appropriately, upsert in the database, and then close the connection. However, it seems like the function is not closing the connection as expected, instead it appears to be sleeping and not finalizing.

My function.json:

```js
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "tabproductsOldCategory",
      "type": "sql",
      "direction": "out",
      "commandText": "external_source.tab_products_old_category",
      "connectionStringSetting": "SQLConnectionString"
    },
    {
      "name": "tabproducts",
      "type": "sql",
      "direction": "out",
      "commandText": "external_source.tab_products",
      "connectionStringSetting": "SQLConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:05:00"
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.my-func": "Information",
      "default": "None"
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what makes you think it's not closing connections and just sleeping instead? Do you have logs?

Comment: Thank you @DeanMacGregor 
Looking in the database it is showing that the user is status> 'Sleeping' and Command: 'AWAITING COMMAND' 
https://prnt.sc/fBTvbQiVKSfa
https://prnt.sc/cxRlaQeHn39Z

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Azure Functions automatically handles opening and closing connections as needed and no need to explicitly close the connections to external resources like databases.

- Try using finally block to close the connection.
- Set the Timeout setting `"functionTimeout":"00:20:00"` setting in `host.json`.

> I was expecting the function to process the request, handle the num_sq or num_pd field in the request appropriately, upsert in the database, and then close the connection.

I have reproduced your requirement in my environment.

- Created two tables `tabproductsOldCategory` and `tabproducts` in my SQL Database.

**Code Snippet:**

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, tabproductsOldCategory: func.Out[func.SqlRow], tabproducts: func.Out[func.SqlRow]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info("Python HTTP trigger and SQL output binding function processed a request.")

    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        products = [item for item in req_body if "num_pd" in item.keys()]
        OldCategory = [item for item in req_body if "num_sq" in item.keys()]

        logging.info(f"Processed request body. Found {len(products)} products and {len(OldCategory)} OldCategory.")

        rows_products = func.SqlRowList(map(func.SqlRow.from_dict, products))
        rows_OldCategory = func.SqlRowList(map(func.SqlRow.from_dict, OldCategory))

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse("An error occurred while processing your request.", status_code=500)

    try:
        if rows_products:
            logging.info("UPSERTING products")
            tabproducts.set(rows_products)
            logging.info("products UPSERTED")

        if rows_OldCategory:
            logging.info("UPSERTING OldCategory")
            tabproductsOldCategory.set(rows_OldCategory)
            logging.info("OldCategory UPSERTED")

        return func.HttpResponse(
            body=req.get_body(),
            status_code=201,
            mimetype="application/json",
        )

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("An error occurred while upserting the rows into the SQL tables.")
        logging.error(f"Exception: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error processing request: {e}", status_code=400)
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "SqlConnectionString":"<Sql_connection_string>"
  }
}
```

**function.json:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
      {
        "name": "req",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "methods": [
          "post"
        ],
        "authLevel": "anonymous"
      },
      {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "$return"
      },
      {
        "name": "tabproductsOldCategory",
        "type": "sql",
        "direction": "out",
        "connectionStringSetting": "SqlConnectionString",
        "commandText": "dbo.tabproductsOldCategory"
      },
      {
        "name": "tabproducts",
        "type": "sql",
        "direction": "out",
        "connectionStringSetting": "SqlConnectionString",
        "commandText": "dbo.tabproducts"
      }
    ],
    "disabled": false
}
```

- Inserting data to the SQL Database by sending data as Post request via POSTMAN:

[image]

**Console Output:**

```py
(env) c:\Users\uname\httpfn>func start
Found Python version 3.11.8 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5455 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.27.5.21554

[2024-03-06T10:21:29.718Z] Customer packages not in sys path. This should never happen! 
[2024-03-06T10:21:34.979Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpTrigger: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-06T10:21:40.023Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.   
[2024-03-06T10:34:58.025Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=e257de76-0e5a-44a6-8a7e-1b9e3e0066b5)
[2024-03-06T10:34:58.151Z] UPSERTING OldCategory
[2024-03-06T10:34:58.151Z] Python HTTP trigger and SQL output binding function processed a request.      
[2024-03-06T10:34:58.151Z] Processed request body. Found 1 products and 1 OldCategory.
[2024-03-06T10:34:58.151Z] UPSERTING products
[2024-03-06T10:34:58.151Z] products UPSERTED
[2024-03-06T10:34:58.151Z] OldCategory UPSERTED
[2024-03-06T10:35:07.602Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=e257de76-0e5a-44a6-8a7e-1b9e3e0066b5, Duration=9538ms)
```

**Portal:**

- Inserted the data successfully.

**tabproducts table:**

[image]

**tabproductsOldCategory table:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I've copied all the information, However, the issue persists, with tasks accumulating without completing automatically. Looking into sp_who2, it shows that it is "AWAITING COMMAND". Upon reviewing the 'host.json', I noticed that the 'version' is set to '2.0'. While I understand that this corresponds to the V2 model for Python, I remember it being always that. This problem began occurring in February without any modifications. Is a possibility converting this code to Python V2 being a solution, or better to set Version: 1.0?
https://prnt.sc/cxRlaQeHn39Z